# User Resources Expanded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, railstutorial.org

In order to more clearly understand exactly what "resources" is doing in the Ruby on Rails routes.rb file, I want to write under it the exact code it is replacing.

When I run rake routes I get this:

```
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

Can someone help me fill in the blanks below so I can understand this more clearly:

```
  resources 'users'
  # get 'users' => 'users#index"
  # post ...
  # get ...
  # get ...
  # patch ...
  # put ...
  # delete ...
```

Comment: Check this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: Thanks, but I want to write the actual equivilent code that would be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent code could be expressed as:

```
get 'users', to: 'users#index'
post 'users', to: 'users#create'
get 'users/new', to: 'users#new', as: 'new_user'
get 'users/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'edit_user'
get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
patch 'users/:id', to: 'users#update'
put 'users/:id', to: 'users#update'
delete 'users/:id', to: 'users#destroy'
```

Comment: Thank you Brad. This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there an alternate convention for writing these (e.g., get 'new_user' => 'users#new')

Comment: You're welcome. You have a few options for mixing it up. For example, you can use `match` (with `via`), instead of `get`. Also, you can leave off the `as`, and it will sometimes make it for you (but it will be "wrong"). You can do pretty much anything you want, to adjust or improve these. One think that I like to do (I almost put it in the answer, but I didn't want to muddle things) is to consolidate `create`, `new`, `edit` and `update` into a single super-dry controller action and view whenever possible.

Comment: @woodenfox Finally, it might be worth pointing out that you can view the source for resources at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources. Note that it takes namespaces and whatnot into account automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`Brad werth`s answer is what you need.

---

To give you some more context, you also need to appreciate how the [*resourceful* routing system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) works in Rails...

> Resource routing allows you to quickly declare all of the common routes for a given resourceful controller. Instead of declaring separate routes for your `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions, a resourceful route declares them in a single line of code.

Basically, each time you call `resources`, you're telling rails to build a set of routes for a controller designed around the "resourceful" principle.

"Resourceful" actions through the Internet are defined by wikipedia as follows:

> HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model. A web browser, for example, may be the client and an application running on a computer hosting a web site may be the server. The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which **provides *resources* such as HTML files and other content**, or performs other functions on behalf of the client, returns a response message to the client. The response contains completion status information about the request and may also contain requested content in its message body.

All of this make sense when you understand that Ruby/Rails is [`object orientated`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This means *everything* you do in your application has to resolve around the initialization & maintenance of "objects".

Objects are basically your *models* - they are created, edited and destroyed ([CRUD -- create read update destroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)) with your controller actions. Therefore, to give you a set of standardized routes, you'll be able to use the following:

[image]

If you want to see your routes like how `brad` has outlined, you'll want to run `rake routes`

--

Good resource here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/difference-between-rest-and-crud